# PyTorch equivalent of a Tensorflow loss function

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I was trying to reimplement a TensorFlow code using PyTorch framework. Below I have included the TF sample code and my PyT interpretation, for a target of size `(Batch, 9, 9, 4)` and a network output of size `(Batch, 9, 9, 4)`

TensorFlow implementation:

```
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)
loss = tf.matrix_band_part(loss, 0, -1) - tf.matrix_band_part(loss, 0, 0)
```

PyTorch implementation:

```
output = torch.tensor(output, requires_grad=True).view(-1, 4)
target = torch.tensor(target).view(-1, 4).argmax(1)

loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')
my_loss = loss(output, target).view(-1,9,9)
```

For the PyTorch implementation, I'm not sure how to implement `tf.matrix_band_part`. I was thinking about defining a mask, but I was not sure if that would hurt the backpropagation or not. I am aware of `torch.triu`, but this function does not work for tensors with more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: `torch.triu` works with batches well (as [per docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=triu#torch.triu)). You can get diagonal elements via [`einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=einsum#torch.einsum): `torch.einsum('...ii->...i', A)`.

Comment: btw mask doesn't hurt backprop

Comment: You are right, they added this very recently. I upgraded to PyTorch 1.3.0 and it works fine. You can write this as response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (at least) version 1.2.0 `torch.triu` works with batches well (as [per docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=triu#torch.triu)).

You can get diagonal elements via [`einsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=einsum#torch.einsum): `torch.einsum('...ii->...i', A)`.

Applying mask doesn't hurt backprop. You can think about it as projection (which is obviously works well with backprop).